# My code is displaying both options?

Tags: php, attributes, product-attribute, product-view

I'm trying to display the information from an attribute with information as to when the product will be available again on my custom `view.phtml` page. This is my code:

```
<div class="col2-set">
    <div class="col-1">
        <?php if ($_product->getShortDescription()):?>
                <div class="short-description std">
                    <?php // Check to see if the item is in stock
                    if($_product->stock_item->is_in_stock == 1):
                        echo $this->__('Availability') ?>:<strong><?php echo $this->__('In stock') ?></strong>

                    <?php else: ?>
                        <strong><?php echo $this->__('This product is available on: ') ?></strong><?php echo $_product->getAvailabilitydate(); ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getShortDescription()), 'short_description') ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
```

However, it is now displaying both. So when a product is not in stock it's displaying not in stock AND my custom attribute information. What am I missing here?

Comment: So you want to show only Availability Date not both things as Out of stock & Availability Date?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how can If and Else, both work at the same time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Copy the below file in your theme

> /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml

2. instead Out of stock label use your code to show Availability Date.

Comment: Thanks! I have no idea why I missed this in the first place, haha

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

try this checking the stock

```
<?php if($_product->getStockItem()->getIsInStock() == 1):
       echo $this->__('Availability') ?>
       :<strong><?php echo $this->__('In stock') ?></strong>
<?php else: ?>
      <strong><?php echo $this->__('This product is available on: ') ?></strong><?php echo $_product->getAvailabilitydate(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```